# Program crashes with 0xC0000005

Tags: c

I been trying to run my code but always ends with the error code 0xC0000005

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void calculate_resistance(char metal, int length, int diameter, float   resistivity);

int main()
{
   int length, diameter;
   float resistivity;
   char metal;
   printf("Enter the name of the metal: ");
   scanf("%s", &metal);
   printf("Enter the resistivity: ");
   scanf("%f", &resistivity);
   printf("Enter the length: ");
   scanf("%d", &length);
   printf("Enter the diameter: ");
   scanf("%d", &diameter);
   calculate_resistance(metal, length, diameter, resistivity);
   return 0;
}

void calculate_resistance(char metal, int length, int diameter, float resistivity)
{
   float radius = diameter / 2;
   float area_of_wire = (M_PI) * pow(radius,2) * length;
   float resistance = resistivity * length / area_of_wire;
   printf("Resistivity of %s is %f", metal, resistance);
}
```

I found that if I comment out "printf("Resistivity of %s is %f", metal, resistance);" or any printf after the last scanf it will not crash with the error code 0xC0000005

Comment: `char metal;` --> `char metal[96];` (proper size), `void calculate_resistance(char metal,` --> `void calculate_resistance(char metal[],`

Answer (score 2):

```
char metal;
```

declares a *single `char`*. It can store just *one* character. You want to store a collection of characters, i.e, a *string*. So use

```
char metal[50]; /* Can store a max of 49 chars +1 for the \0 */
```

After that, leave out the `&` from

```
scanf("%s", &metal);
```

because the name of an array gets converted to a pointer to its first element already. For added security, you can prevent a length modifier in the format specifier denoting the maximum number of characters minus 1 (1 space reserved for the NUL-terminator):

```
scanf("%49s", metal);
```

Also, you should provide some more error checking and also check if all the `scanf`s are successful by having a look at its return value.
Don't forget to change `char metal` to `char metal[]` or `char* metal` in the function declaration and definition too as you aren't passing a single character, rather, the array (Actually, pointer to its first element because arrays "decay").

Comment: @M.M Thanks. Added suggestion to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
char metal;
printf("Enter the name of the metal: ");
scanf("%s", &metal);
```

This code invokes an undefined behavior. You are trying to store sequence of characters in the one `char` variable. You should use either `%c` format specifier, or an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

The variable metal is a char. This holds only 1 character. You need to hold an array of characters.

```
char metal[100];
```

Of course 100 may not be good for your case, but using `char` and `%s` for `scanf` and `printf` will cause issues.